# Can I control Lighting2D intensity with script? (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

people, I have little problem. I need to have access on 2D light intensity from script. I tried doing it with GetComponent<>, but it didn't work. Maybe, I did something wrong with GetComponent<>, because I'm starter.
[Screenshot of what I want to control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd7DI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call for `GetComponent<>()` but you might be doing it wrong.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal;

    public class ControllingIntensity : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float intensity;

        void Start()
        {
            GetComponent<Light2D>().intensity = intensity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Update: On unity 2021.3 LTS you must use: using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;